# Consume a WCF Data Service without adding a service reference

Tags: wcf, wcf-data-services, wcf-data-services-client

How can I consume a WCF Data Service without adding a Service Reference.

For a normal WCF service, we use shared contracts and create proxy at runtime to call the service. Is similar concept possible in case of Data Service?

Comment: Publish WCF Service to the server, Get the URL and test it in the browser if it's returning data in XML/JSON format, then Use that URL in your program(C#) to fetch the data using HttpRequest etc... if you want to consume it in JavaScript then use ajax request.

Comment: @Muhammadimran Thank you for your comment..! Is there any other way similar to what we do for WCF using channel ?

Comment: Channel seems not a good option; it needs access to your assemblies. Creating and using proxy is a good option rather. see following links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308876/direct-channel-usage-vs-using-a-proxy and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1698275/wcf-channelfactory-vs-generating-proxy

Comment: @Muhammadimran - Proxy is definately a better option. Thank you..!! Also, I was wondering if we can expose DTO classes instead of actual entities with Data Service??

Comment: In this case you've to write custom provider. Auto generated ones are recommended though.